# Is it possible to invert the order errors are displayed?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When compiling a faulty program with GHC, errors are displayed in ascending line order. That causes the first errors to get pushed up the console, so you need to scroll up if you work by fixing the first errors first, which may be annoying. Is it possible to ask GHC to print errors in descending line order?

Comment: What a great question! I hadn't even realised I had this problem

Comment: I'm wondering if there's an option to make ghc _stop_ after the first error like `-Wfatal-errors` for GCC.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this with the **`-freverse-errors`** option flag of the GHC compiler. So you should compile it with:

```
ghc -freverse-errors code.hs
```

Like the [documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html#warnings) says:

> ```
> -freverse-errors
> ```
>
> Display errors in GHC/GHCi sorted by reverse order of source code line numbers.

Since this option is *dynamic*, you can set this option *per file*. So you can add the following to files for which you want to enable this:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -freverse-errors #-}
```

Since this is - to the best of my knowledge - a GHC specific flag, it will probably *not* work for other compilers (and of course older versions of the GHC compiler).

Comment: Thanks. `--ghc-arg=-freverse-errors` seems to work for `runghc`.

Comment: This is so handy! I can't believe there is already an option for this. XD